# C++ Constructor Implementation Error

Tags: c++

C++ Constructor Implementation Error

I have 2 class

```
Map2D(parent) & Map3D(child)
```

So this is what happen...

```
class Map3D : public Map2D
{
private:
int z;

public:
Map3D();
Map3D(int,int,int);
int getZ();

}
```

And below is my Map2D

```
class Map2D
{

friend ifstream& operator>>(ifstream&, Map2D&);

protected:
int x;
int y;

public:
Map2D();
Map2D(int,int);

};

Map2D::Map2D()
{
x=0;
y=0;
}

Map2D::Map2D(int xIn,int yIn)
{
x = xIn;
y = yIn;
}
```

The problem now is i try to implement Map3D but got issue.. which what i try is below

Back on Map3D.cpp

```
Map3D::Map3D()
{
x=0;
y=0;
z=0;
}

Map3D::Map3D(int xIn,int yIn,int zIn)
{
x=xIn;
y=yIn;
z=zIn;
}

map3d.cpp:18:1: error: extra qualification ‘map3D::’ on member ‘map3D’ [-fpermissive]
map3d.cpp:18:1: error: ‘map3D::map3D()’ cannot be overloaded
map3d.cpp:14:1: error: with ‘map3D::map3D()’
map3d.cpp:25:1: error: extra qualification ‘map3D::’ on member ‘map3D’ [-fpermissive]
map3d.cpp:25:1: error: ‘map3D::map3D(int, int, int)’ cannot be overloaded
map3d.cpp:15:1: error: with ‘map3D::map3D(int, int, int)’
```

What should i change to make my implementation correct. Thanks for all help.

Comment: Unfortunately the code you pasted here doesn't correspond to the error message you gave us (`map3D` vs `Map3D`) so it's going to be hard to diagnose.

Comment: @MarkB It's amazing, you think cutting and pasting code would be easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a missing semi-colon at the end of the `Map3D` declaration

```
class Map3D : public Map2D
{
private:
int z;

public:
Map3D();
Map3D(int,int,int);
int getZ();

}; // SEMI-COLON HERE!!!!
```